# Library to convert python string to valid HTML id?

Tags: python

I am generating HTML id attributes from python strings.  Is there a library that can convert a string to a valid id?  Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id, the id attribute can't have whitespaces and for compatibility should only have a few non-alphanumeric characters.

If it makes a difference, I am using the Jinja2 template engine.

**Update for clarification**: I realize I can write my own code, but I was looking for something that already in use, and most importantly, correct.

Comment: Have you considered writing one yourself? Something like `id = (c for c in s if c.isalnum()).split().join("-")` should get you most of the way there. You could implement it as a Jinja2 filter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a library but you could just remove characters apart from a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and ._- that are allowed like this

```
import re
htmltag = re.sub('[^(a-z)(A-Z)(0-9)._-]', '', pythonstring) 

if htmltag=='':
     print "no good"
else:
    print 'proposed tag', htmltag
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be useful if you mention what your aim is here. What are you going to use these ids for? You need to be careful about where you get the strings from to use as ids as you need to ensure they are unique on the page after conversion / sanitisation.

This is similar to other solutions posted but also allows for underscores, dashes and periods. It also makes sure the identifier starts with a letter (note this will fail and return an empty string if the identifier does not contain any ascii letters) -

```
import string

safe = string.letters + string.digits + '_-.'

def string_to_html_id(s):
    s = ''.join([letter for letter in s if letter in safe])
    while not s[0] in string.letters:
        s = s[1:] # Remove the first character until it starts with a letter
    return s

print(string_to_html_id(r'_Hello fsd-klj @(*)^&*sf.kj 34_54')) # prints Hellofsd-kljsf.kj34_54
```